# How can I make RefCounting optional inside an allocator class trough template police class design?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

My pool allocators have an inner class Block, that goes like this:

```
template<class T> PoolAlloc{
...
 struct Block{
  T userData;
  RefCounting rc;
 };
 Block * m_pPool;
...
};
```

I dont know how to make the refcounting optional in an elegant way.
Passing an external Block as an extra template parameter is ugly, since I will have to give the T parameter to both the allocator and for the allocator parameter:

```
PoolAlloc<Foo, Block<Foo>>
```

Its redundant.
I tried specializing only the inner struct, but its my understanding this aint an option, inner classes require entire outter class specialization:

```
template<class T, bool refCounting> PoolAlloc{
...
 struct Block;
...
};
template <class T, bool RC> struct PoolAlloc<T,RC>::Block{ T userData; RefCounting rc;};// default
template<class T> struct PoolAlloc<T, false>::Block{ T userData;}; // cant get this to compile
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is most likely easier than you think.

Imagine you have struct/class and you want to make something inside it optional (aka there or not there) this is the "policy" for want of a better word. The first thing you need to do is define 2 structs one with the real implementation and one with an empty implementation then depending on which you want you instantiate that. There is no other way of implementing this BTW so you will have to make do with some redundancy here. (Defaulted `template` parameters and `template using` can help reduce the redundancy a bit here.)

For example (not tested):

```
struct empty_ref_counter {
    //empty reference counter implementation
    void add_reference() {} // <-- no implementation!!
    //other empty member functions
};

struct ref_counter {
    //reference counter implmentation
    unsigned ref;
    void add_reference() {
         ++ref;
    }
    //other complete member functions
};

template<typename RefCountPolicy = empty_ref_counter>
struct strA {
    typedef typename RefCountPolicy ref_policy;
    RefCountPolicy count;
};
```

Note I did a `typedef typename` of `ref_policy` this is the reference policy used by `strA` and can be used to inspect the `ref_policy` by outside sources (aka functions that take a `strA<RCP>`).

In other words you can make Block a `template struct`, and still have access to `T` in the outer `template` `class`/`struct`.

```
 struct BlockBase {};
 template<typename RefCount>
 struct Block : BlockBase {
  T userData;
  RefCount rc;
 };
 BlockBase* m_pPool;
```

In order to do this it may also be a good idea to give Block a non template base (possibly even with virtual destructor to ensure RefCount is properly destructed!!)

Comment: I did something based on what you said, but different from what you showed, lol.
I just have this now inside the pool class:
`struct RefCountedBlock; struct LeanBlock;`
`using Block = std::conditional_t<RefCounted, RefCountedBlock, LeanBlock>;`
`Block * m_pool;`
RefCounted is a bool parameter template on the outter class. Its basically a specialization.

Comment: That would work, I guess. I like my version but you can still do it that way too.